# Как сформировать SQL запрос с сортировкой по нескольким полям

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Пишу магазин, хочу реализовать задачу сортировки товаров в каталоге.
Нужно чтобы товары с нулевой ценой и остатком отображались в конце списка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С нулевой ценой я понял как быть:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY CASE WHEN price = 0 THEN 1000000000000 END, price LIMIT 0, 10
```

А вот как еще переместить нулевые остатки не пойму.

Сортировать на PHP не вариант, так как для пагинации задан лимит вывода LIMIT 0, 10. Пробовал что-то в таком духе, но получается не то:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY
        CASE
            WHEN stock != 0 THEN 1000000000000
        END, stock DESC,
        CASE
            WHEN price = 0 THEN 1000000000000
        END, price ASC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
ORDER BY stock=0,
         price=0,
         stock DESC,
         price
```

Как итог. Все `stock=0, price=0` окажутся в конце. Выше будут `stock=0, price!=0`, затем `stock!=0, price=0`, и в самом верху будут `stock!=0, price!=0`. В каждой группе отдельно записи будут сортированы сперва по `stock DESC`, а при равном `stock` - по `price ASC`.

PS. В данных есть ещё и NULL - следует помнить, что в MySQL NULL меньше любого другого значения. Если нужно это изменить - следует добавить ещё уровни сортировки по выражению `column IS [NOT] NULL`.

Comment: @Tyler Пока, по этому объяснению - пофиг, где будут NULL, в начале товаров с остатком, в конце или середине. Главное - выведены. Или уточняйте (причём это надо добавить в текст вопроса апдейтом, а не в комментарии), куда должны быть помещены записи со значением NULL. При нынешнем `stock DESC` они должны быть в самом конце блоков `stock!=0`...

Answer (score 1):

Этот вариант работает для меня наилучшим образом:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY
CASE
   WHEN price = 0 THEN 1000000000000
   WHEN stock = 0 THEN 1000000000000 ELSE 0
END,
price ASC,
stock ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

P.S. Если кому пригодится, учтите что в моем примере поле price по-умолчанию 0 и не может быть NULL, stock по-умолчанию NULL. Оба значения имеют тип float.